# How do I tell the designer that my custom winforms control has a fixed height?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, designer

I've made a custom control and overridden `SetBoundsCore` such that the height of the control is fixed.  I'd like the designer to show the same sort of resize boxes as the `NumericUpDown` has - just one at each end - so that it's clear that the control has a fixed height.  How do I tell the designer that my control has a fixed height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply a `Designer` attribute to your `UserControl`:

```
[Designer(typeof(UCDesigner))]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

  public UserControl1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

}
```

The `UCDesigner` class is defined as follow:

```
class UCDesigner : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner {

  public override System.Windows.Forms.Design.SelectionRules SelectionRules {
    get {
      return (base.SelectionRules & ~(SelectionRules.BottomSizeable | SelectionRules.TopSizeable));
    }
  }

}
```

Note: You'll have to add a reference to the System.Design namespace.